# Default date for insert doesn't change in continuous transformation

Tags: postgresql, pipelinedb

I created the table below.

```
create table foo 
(   
  ibutton text NULL,
  severidade int4 NULL,
  dt_insercao timestamptz NULL DEFAULT now()
)
```

My insert:

```
insert into foo (ibutton, severidade) values ('aa', 4);
```

For any cases of the value of 'dt_insersao', which should be default "now", is always going as '2017-06-08 10:35:35'...

I don't have idea  where does it's come from this value..

This insert are executed into my continuous transformation.

These inserts are executed into my continuous transformation of the pipelinedb. When I execute in my client PGAdmin, the date are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how PipelineDB comes into play here, but in Postgres, `now()` returns the same value for all inserts in a single transaction:

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the "current" time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.

If you need a different value for each row that is inserted in one transaction use `clock_timestamp()` instead in your table definition.